# Where is WebKit + V8?

Tags: javascript, c++, webkit

Are there any WebKit ports that use V8 (or can be built so) and be easily used in any GUI system?

(I've checked some WebKit-GTK+ branch but it doesn't even compile because of some errors in the code.)

I've seen there are some Chromium ports on WebKit's website. Does it include V8? Is it the same Chromium when compiled?

Comment: V8 is the JavaScript engine in Chrome. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29)

Comment: Yes, but it can be easily integrated anywhere. I want WebKit that uses V8 as JavaScript engine. (normally, WebKit uses JavaScriptCore)

Comment: Chrome is based on WebKit too.

Comment: I know and I know it uses V8 but I want WebKit that uses V8 as a library so that I could use it in my project rather than an application.

Comment: So you want something like a UIWebView component, except with V8.

Comment: Yes I understand; that's the only browser component whose name I know so I just used it as an example :-)

Comment: The qt porting could use the V8 engine. There is an option '--v8' in 'build-webkit' script, which says 'Use V8 as JavaScript engine (Qt only)'. But, I never have a try.

Answer (score -2):

Have u tried NW.js ie node-webkit